# Free virtualization platforms with good VM configuration options (like processor frequency)

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine

I need virtualization platform which would be used for non-commercial purpose. I have experience with VMWare Player. With VMWare player I don't like the fact that I cannot set processor frequency. I am not happy with configurable options in general.

I would like to have option of migration my VMs between virtualization platforms. 
I know that last year Citrix went open source. Any details are welcomed.

I am aware that this looks mandatory, but I just want to give good directions with some specific requirements.

Comment: What OS are your trying to virtualize?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using **[Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)** for virtualization. Comes with a nice front-end making administration pretty easy, and supports a lot of different operating systems. According to a post on our sister-site ([Limiting CPU speed in a virtual machine?](https://superuser.com/q/265322/143340) – see e.g. [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/516414/143340)), it is possible to set the required CPU frequency.

Additionally, *VirtualBox* can read VMWare images – so you even could use your already existing VMs with it. You can start VMs with the existing GUI – but if needed, you can also have them running "headless" (comes quite handy if you run them on a remote server). VMs can be connected to remotely via any [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) viewer, which makes it easy to work with even remote VMs (e.g. such running on a server at a different location).